# Type Mul problem while using numpyexp in python

Tags: python, loops, callable

When I try to write this equation

```
import numpy as np
y = Function("y")
t = Symbol('t')

dy2 = Derivative(y(t), t,2)
dy1 = 3 * Derivative(y(t),t)
eq1 = Eq(dy2 + dy1 - 4 * y(t), 2 * np.exp(-4*t))
eq1
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'exp'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-162-77ead41bd3d6> in <module>
      5 dy2 = Derivative(y(t), t,2)
      6 dy1 = 3 * Derivative(y(t),t)
----> 7 eq1 = Eq(dy2 + dy1 - 4 * y(t), 2 * np.exp(-4*t))
      8 eq1

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable exp method
```

What is the problem and How can I solve it?